# Reading and debouncing multiple controller keys with evdev

Tags: python, controller, evdev

I have an 8bitdo NES controller that I have hooked up to a Raspberry Pi and am using it to interact with some various demos I'm working on.

I'm trying to figure out a good way to grab multiple keypresses with `evdev` while debouncing so that a single keypress doesn't trigger twice.  I could set a flag and check the next loop, but thought this might be taken care of with the library.

I'm using the `active_keys` function to get a list of all keypresses as using the `for event in device.read_loop():` call appears to be blocking and only grabs a single key per loop.

This is where I'm currently at:

```
# define key values
KEY_L = 294

while not done:
  keys = gamepad.active_keys()
  if KEY_L:
    # handle L bumper
  ...
```

As I mentioned, I could set a flag per key to handle a debounce which would get quickly redundant and thought there was a more elegant way to handle this.  I didn't notice it in the [API documentation](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc.html) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the `evdev` source that there is a [debounce](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/blob/master/src/evdev-debounce.c) class, but it doesn't appear to be accessible from the Python interface.

A flag per key with a pause and a re-read is a simple and widely used method you appear to be familiar with. You can do it somewhat elegantly with Python's [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
def active_keys_debounced(debounce_delay=10):
    """Return a list of all debounced keys. Debounce delay is in ms."""
    keys = gamepad.active_keys()
    time.sleep(debounce_delay/1000)
    return list(set(keys).intersection(gamepad.active_keys()))
```

A more sophisticated method could be to use an [integrator](https://www.kennethkuhn.com/electronics/debounce.c).

Alternatively, you could also try using [events](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events) or [async events](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-using-asyncio) if you really want it to be fast. These may be automatically debounced, but I'm not sure:

```
>>> from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
>>> dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')

>>> print(dev)
device /dev/input/event1, name "Dell Dell USB Keyboard", phys "usb-0000:00:12.1-2/input0"

>>> for event in dev.read_loop():
...     if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
...         print(categorize(event))
... # pressing 'a' and holding 'space'
key event at 1337016188.396030, 30 (KEY_A), down
key event at 1337016188.492033, 30 (KEY_A), up
key event at 1337016189.772129, 57 (KEY_SPACE), down
key event at 1337016190.275396, 57 (KEY_SPACE), hold
key event at 1337016190.284160, 57 (KEY_SPACE), up
```

Comment: i really like that `intersection` method, thanks!